# Taxonomy archive + query attachments = duplicate results

Tags: taxonomy, attachments, duplicates

I'm trying to get the attachments of a specific term (in its archive page). But the results are showing the resulting images 5 times instead of one.

I have multiple loops in this page - one to show related posts, another to show related products (custom post), and this one to show related images. Custom posts and posts are working nicely, but I can't show the attachments in the right way. :S

```
<?php $queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id; 

$args = array(
'post_status' => 'inherit',
'numberposts' => 0,
'post__not_in' => array_merge($do_not_duplicate,get_option( 'sticky_posts' )),
'post_type' => 'attachment',
);

$args['tax_query'] = array(
array(
    'taxonomy' => 't-arte',
    'terms' => $term_id,
    'field' => 'id',
),
); ?>

<?php $t = $data['t-arte'];
$array = explode(" ", $t);
$array = array_unique($array);?>

<?php $media_query = array_unique($array); ?>

<?php $media_query = get_posts($args);
if( !empty( $media_query ) ) :
foreach ($media_query as $media_query) :
global $post; $post = $media_query;
setup_postdata($media_query);
?>

<div id="archivespage-media-item">   

<?php $attachments = get_posts( $args );
                 if ( $attachments ) {
                    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                       echo '<div id="imagem">';
                       the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, true );
                       echo '</div>';
                       }
                 }?>

</div>

<?php endforeach;else :?>       

<p>Ainda não temos nenhuma imagem relacionada :(</p>  

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: What have you done to **debug**? What have you done to track down the source of the issue? Are you getting duplicate *attachments*, or duplicate *posts* with attachments?

Comment: Hi Chip! Sorry, I dont understand what do you mean as debug. 

I'm getting duplicate attachments. I wanna show the attachments with the same term. The results of attachments are showing 5 times. You can see a test here in topic "Imagens Relacionadas » Sakimi Chan" http://colorbits.com.br/t-arte/sakimi-chan/

Comment: Looking at the output, I think you're getting duplicate *posts*, not duplicate *attachments*. More specifically, it looks like you're getting the same post, 5 times. For debugging, I would recommend verifying your query return values at each point that you loop through them. Start here: `$media_query = get_posts($args); var_dump( $media_query )`. Then try here: `$attachments = get_posts( $args ); var_dump( $attachments )`.

Comment: Related question: why are you passing the *same arguments array* to `$media_query` *and* `$attachments`? Don't you need to query *children* for `$attachments`?

Comment: I didnt found another way to show attachments :(

Comment: I've put var_dump on code, please take a look at the page, I really dont know what that means...

Comment: "*I didnt found another way to show attachments*" - how about [`get_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children)?

Comment: "*I've put var_dump on code, please take a look at the page, I really dont know what that means*" - that is the raw query output. You need to look through it, and determine if it's returning the posts that you expect to be queried.

Comment: Yes, the posts are right and the attachments are right. But are showing 5 times the same.

I've tried to put this in place of `$attachments = get_posts( $args ); ....`

`<?php $images = get_children( $args );
if ($images) {
foreach ($images as $image) 
{echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'full');
}}?>`

But now the images are gone.
Sorry, I'm really new with PHP

Comment: Are you passing the right arguments to `get_children()`? I find it very hard to believe that the arguments passed to `$media_query` will be **exactly the same** as the arguments passed to a query that fetches images attached to the posts returned in `$media_query`.

Comment: So, I need to get attachments without an args??

Comment: "*So, I need to get attachments without an args?*" - No, you need to use the *proper args*. :)

Comment: Let me see if I get it: I should put $media_query to query for 'tax_query' and $images to query for 'post_type' => 'attachment' ?

Comment: I think so, yes. Your `$attachments` query should be looking for images attached specifically to the current post in the `$media_query` loop.

Comment: Also, where is `$data` defined? That's what you're actually passing to `$media_query`.

Comment: I've tried these, but its not filtering by term anymore. -_-' 

`$args['tax_query'] = array(
 array('taxonomy' => 't-arte',
'terms' => $term_id,
'field' => 'id',),); 
  
$media_query = new WP_Query( $args)?>
<?php  if($media_query->have_posts()) : while ($media_query->have_posts() ) : $media_query->the_post();?>
        
<div><?php $images = get_children( array ('post_type' => 'attachment') ); if ($images) { foreach ($images as $image) {
echo '<div id="imagem">'; echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'full');
echo '</div>'; }}?>`

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the problem is that you're passing the wrong arguments to the `$attachments` query, causing you not to get the intended posts in the `$attachments` query.

Here's what you're doing:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'numberposts' => 0,
    'post__not_in' => array_merge($do_not_duplicate,get_option( 'sticky_posts' )),
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
);

$args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 't-arte',
        'terms' => $term_id,
        'field' => 'id',
    ),
);

$attachments = get_posts( $args );
```

So, you're querying *all* posts that are post-type `attachment`, rather than *only* the posts that are attached to the current post being looped through in `$media_query`.

Here's how you loop through `$media_query`:

```
foreach ($media_query as $media_query) :
```

(Note: bad form. Try something like `foreach ( $media_query as $media ) :` instead.)

You need to pass the ID of the current post to your `$attachments` query, as `post_parent`. Something simple might be:

```
$attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_parent' => $media_query->ID
    'numberposts' => 0
) );
```

Comment: I've tried it, but now its showing some random images that aren't related to the taxonomy term '$term_id' :/

`$media_query = get_posts($args);
if( !empty( $media_query ) ) :
foreach ( $media_query as $media ) :
            global $post; $post = $media_query;
            setup_postdata($media_query);`

And attachments query as you shown.

Comment: My code was just example code. You'll need to adapt it as necessary (such as adding your `tax_query`).

Comment: If you could take a look at these: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/call-to-a-member-function-have_posts-on-taxonomy-archive-query-attachments?replies=2

It works fine! But has an error right behind the attachments that I want:
Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object in...

The result here: http://colorbits.com.br/t-arte/sakimi-chan/

Comment: Chip! I got it! :D I made something like these! http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29635/how-to-create-an-attachments-archive-with-working-pagination Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it! The result will show all attachments in a specific term inside term's archive page. Thanks Chip!

```
<?php $queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id; 

 global $wp_query;

 $original_query['tax_query'] = array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 't-arte',
'terms' => $term_id,
'field' => 'id',
),);

   $original_query = (array) $wp_query;

$attach_query = array(
    'post_type'=> array( 'attachment' ),
    'post_status' => array( null ));
$args = array_merge($original_query['query_vars'], $attach_query);

$media_query = new WP_Query( $args )?>

<?php  if($media_query->have_posts()) :
while ($media_query->have_posts() ) : $media_query->the_post();
if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>

<div id="archivespage-media-item">   

<div id="imagem">
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID, 'bigger-thumb');?>
     </div>

</div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>    

//do stuff       

 </div>
```